# Flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated vs Flask-dance facebook.authorized

Tags: python, facebook, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to build a simple prototype that will have login/password authentication and OAuth2 authentication, the latter with Flask-Dance. So what is the best practice of combining `current_user.is_authenticated` with `facebook.authorized`?

I'm struggling to write the proper logic of login and logout. My code so far looks like this:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated and facebook.authorized: # here is the problem
        me = facebook.get('me?fields=id,first_name,email').json()
        social_id, username, email = me['id'], me['first_name'], me['email']
        user = User.query.filter_by(social_id=social_id).first()
        if not user:
            user = User(social_id=social_id, nickname=username, email=email)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        login_user(user, True)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

And as you can see, once the user logs out, there is no way for her to get back in. However, if I remove the `current_user.is_authenticated` from `if` then the user will stay logged in even after she clicks the logout link.

I'm thinking that the `index` function is not the proper place to handle the Facebook login and that I should somehow hook the actual method that does the OAuth dance, but I need hints on how to do this without plunging into modifying the Flask-Dance code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Flask-Dance. Check the [documentation for multi-user setups](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multi-user.html) to see an example of how to hook into this `oauth_authorized` signal during the user login process.

Answer (score 0):

After raising an issue on GitHub, I'll post the author's response here:

> Neither you nor I can control how Facebook chooses to implement OAuth, and it may choose to give you an OAuth token that has no permissions if the user clicks "cancel" during the authorization step. You can check for this by using the `oauth_authorized` signal, as documented here: http://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html